# Connecting barcode scanner to ipod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, barcode-scanner

I have an ipod touch 4, usb adapter and usb barcode scanner. When I connect the barcode scanner to the ipod through the adapter I am able to scan barcodes but nothing happens on the ipod.

The usb adapter is a generic adapter and has the words "Camera Connection Kit" with a slot for an SD card and a USB plug. The barcode scanner is a generic no-brand scanner that works fine on a laptop or PC.

Do I need a different adapter or does the ipod touch 4 not work with any barcode scanners?

Comment: Those adapters for 30-pin to SD card/storage just make the storage visible.  They don't implement a full USB stack . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a barcode scanner specifically designed for iOS, this likely won't work. There are many great barcode scanning apps that utilize the camera (if your model has one.) I'd recommend Google Goggles.